# MPI_Alltoallw call fails in WSL2

Tags: c++, mpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an MPI program written in C++, which I run on 2+ machines: one is a Fedora machine with an Intel i5-4590T CPU, the other is a Windows machine running Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL 2 (CPU: i7-7820x).
I have the same MPI program on both machines, which calls MPI_Alltoallw. On the Fedora machine, the Alltoallw call works fine and the the output buffer is correctly filled, while on WSL this does not happen and the output buffer is left unmodified by the MPI function call (no errors are given during compile or runtime).

I use in both cases mpic++ (g++ version is 11.3.0 on WSL, 11.3.1 on Fedora) and OpenMPI version 4.1.4.

I also tried the same code on an HPC system (RHEL 8.4, g++ 11.3.0, OpenMPI 4.1.4) and it works fine there as well.

Simpler MPI calls (*e.g.* initializing communicators, a MPI_Bcast) work fine also on WSL.

Is this a known problem with WSL2? Or something like this can arise from a fault in my code?

Edit: here is a minimal example of the code (which also uses Eigen).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    const int nc = 8;
    const int nzc = 8;
    const int nz2 = nzc*nc/2;
    const int nzd = 3*nz2;
    const int nxs2 = 32;
    const int ny = 128;
    const int nyc = ny/nc;

    const int nbytes_cmplxd = 16;

    Eigen::TensorFixedSize<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Sizes<ny, nxs2 + 1, nzc>> xc;
    Eigen::TensorFixedSize<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Sizes<nyc, nxs2+1, nzd>> buf2;

    xc.setRandom(); //xc is set to some values
    buf2.setZero(); 

    int count[nc];
    //initialize counts to 1
    for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
        count[i] = 1;
    }

    //first initializes mpi types and displacements for the transposition from xc to buf2
    //init simple datatypes
    MPI_Datatype sendloc1; 
    MPI_Datatype recvloc1;

    MPI_Type_vector(nzc*(nxs2+1), nyc, ny, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &sendloc1);
    MPI_Type_commit(&sendloc1);

    MPI_Type_vector(nzc*(nxs2+1)*nyc, 1, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &recvloc1);
    MPI_Type_commit(&recvloc1);

    int senddisp1[nc];
    int recvdisp1[nc];
    MPI_Datatype sendtypev1[nc];
    MPI_Datatype recvtypev1[nc];

    for (int i = 0; i<nc; i++) {
        senddisp1[i] = nbytes_cmplxd * i * (nyc); //displacement due to column major ordering

        if (i<(nc/2)) {
            recvdisp1[i] = nbytes_cmplxd * i * (nzc*(nxs2+1)*nyc); //displacement equal to entire size of recvtype
        } else { //add displacement to introduce padding (equal to 1/3 of the array size)
            recvdisp1[i] = nbytes_cmplxd * (i * (nzc*(nxs2+1)*nyc) + nz2*(nxs2+1)*nyc);
        }

        sendtypev1[i] = sendloc1; 
        recvtypev1[i] = recvloc1;
    } 

    //committing the MPI_Datatype vectors is not needed

    MPI_Alltoallw(xc.data(), count, senddisp1, sendtypev1, 
                  buf2.data(), count, recvdisp1, recvtypev1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::cout << buf2 << std::endl; //buf2 is zero after the call

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: At first glance it looks legit. Note you can use `MPI_Alltoallv()` since only one type is used for send and one for recv.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I use `MPI_Alltoallw()` to set the displacement in bytes instead of units of type, since the blocks are interleaved in the receive buffer. Maybe I can resize the original type using `MPI_Type_create_resized` to achieve the same effect but it looked cleaner this way.

Comment: no need, i missed that and you are absolutely right.

Comment: Not sure that interleaving through address trickery is going to work. I'd try the `resized` approach.

Comment: It works fine, just not in WSL2. I only recently started testing the code on the WSL machine, guess I'll go back to the other machines.